# Why do I get Unable to include RenderObjectSuccess.php error when using inline in grid?

Tags: atk4

I'm setting up a grid with an inline field, pretty much the sames than in the examples in the demo, but I just keep getting error: **Unable to include RenderObjectSuccess.php** when chaning the value in the inline field. What a I doing wrong?

```
class page_alumnos_pago extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->api->stickyGET('id');
        $mAlumno=$this->add('Model_Alumno')->loadData($_GET['id']);

        $g = $this->add('Grid');
        $g->addColumn('date','fechaVencimiento');
        $g->addColumn('text','concepto');
        $g->addColumn('money','monto');
        $g->addColumn('inline','temp_pago');    
        $g->setSource('programaPago');
        $g->dq->where('alumno_id',$_GET['id']);
    }
}
```

This is my ProgramaPago model:

```
class Model_ProgramaPago extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='programaPago';
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('alumno_id')->caption('Alumno')->refModel('Model_Alumno')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('fechaVencimiento')->caption('Fecha de Vencimiento')->type('date')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('monto')->caption('Monto')->type('money')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('concepto')->caption('concepto')->type('text')->mandatory(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, that's a bug.

- https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/37
- fix: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commit/3694996

Please let me know if the fix works.

Comment: I just changed that line to: $e=new Exception_StopRender($r);  it works now.

Comment: @mcanedo / @romaninsh, on my version its `throw $this->exception($r,'StopRender');` --- inspecting and comparing other sources, i noticed this exception handling has been changed over time.. is there already a standard in handling exceptions? is there significant difference between changes?

Comment: @OpenTechnologist you are on a "master" branch which has that bug sorted, but it wasn't merged into "devel" branch. Hopefully it's fixed in the 4.1.4 which I announced to devel list.